# Tabs with cookie, completely hide content

Tags: jquery, cookies, tabs

There is tabs with cookie support http://jsfiddle.net/q9Epk/1/ 
the last few lines of code must completely hide content when click selected nav item but it doesn`t work

```
// hide tab
$('ul.tabs li.current').click(function() {
    $('div.section').find('div.box').hide();
    $(this).removeClass('current');

    eraseCookie('tabCookie');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was found in the modification of the function

```
$('ul.tabs').delegate('li:not(.current)', 'click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current')
        .parents('div.section').find('div.box').hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();
    var ulIndex = $('ul.tabs').index($(this).parents('ul.tabs'));
    eraseCookie('tabCookie'+ulIndex);
    createCookie('tabCookie'+ulIndex, $(this).index(), 365);
}).delegate('li.current', 'click', function() {
    $(this).parents('div.section').find('div.box').hide()
    $(this).removeClass('current');

    eraseCookie('tabCookie'+0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q9Epk/2/